# Why is Pycharm IDE so slow when running small games?

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, lag

so i recently started using Pycharm IDE to learn Python. Ive noticed that when I run an application that It runs very slow. Like the project I have isnt big at all but its just very slow at starting and responding to mouse events. Has anyone seen this before? Maybe is it due to my version being a non paid for one (Community download)

Comment: Edition should not be the problem. Do you run your code under the debugger by any chance? It adds a significant overhead to the execution.

Comment: No. Its weird cause i have a brand new computer and Intelllji works fine even for projects with a lot of code. But Pycharm runs pretty slow.

Comment: What is exactly running slow? PyCharm or the game? Are you sure your game doesn't eat up all available system resources?